# use "npx sequelize" locally without install globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sequelize.js, npx

I want to prepare the configuration of my website on a server of my university.

I have the follow problem: `npx sequelize` is not working because sequelize is not installed globally and can't install the package (I not have good rights for that).

There is a way to use sequelize locally?
I need to make migrations and run seeders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried what the [install section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli#installation) tells you to do?

> Make sure you have Sequelize installed. Then install the Sequelize CLI to be used in your project with
>
> ```
> $ npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli
> ```
>
> And then you should be able to run the CLI with
>
> ```
> $ npx sequelize --help
> ```